# Fatal error: Class 'MongoDB\Driver\Manager' not found in /srv/www/api/releases/...vendor/mongodb/mongodb/src/Client.php

Tags: php, mongodb, amazon-web-services, phalcon

I am trying to configure MongoDB on the AWS server, but when I try to make an API call, I get the following error:

```
Fatal error: Class 'MongoDB\Driver\Manager' not found in /srv/www/api/releases/20160912135146/vendor/mongodb/mongodb/src/Client.php on line 56
```

I have done the following:

- Install mongodb, following the instructions here -> [install mongodb community edition on ubuntu](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/)
- installed the php mongodb driver using `pecl install mongodb`
- added `extension=mongodb.so` to php.ini at `etc/php5/cli/php.ini`
- Started the mongodb service
- on the server, I can enter the mongo console with `$ mongo`

What am I missing here, Please?

PS: the API is developed using Phalcon

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally found a solution to this. Apparently, the apache server uses a special `php.ini` file, different from `etc/php5/cli/php.ini`. This file is located in `etc/php5/apache2/php.ini`. After installing the mongodb driver using `pecl install mongodb`, your extension should go in `etc/php5/apache2/php.ini` i.e add `extension = mongodb` at the end of `etc/php5/apache2/php.ini`. Good luck

Comment: The `php.ini` file in the `cli` directory is for when PHP needs to be ran through the `command-line-interface`. Following that logic; the `php.ini` file in the `apache` folder is for PHP ran through your web service, Apache.